# Extra margin appears after body

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7WD7/) I can't post parts of the code because it would be too long.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

The Problem is when you resize the window smaller than 254px it creates a space below the footer and I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: On OS X Chrome it does not

Comment: Have you tried minimizing it?

Comment: Yep. Minimum height was just about the size of the footer.

Comment: @VladNicula I tried on all of the popular browser windows on a Windows PC but the issue is on all of the browsers, after minimizing it really small the body creates a margin after it.

Comment: Just curious, why are you concerned with something that happens below 254px? AFAIK most browsers won't even scale down that far. Also, I assumed you meant width, but @Vlad mentioned height. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be caused because your micro clearfix has `content: "."`.  That full stop has a height because it's a character.

Change the clearfix to:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

The reason it doesn't happen on the wider display is because you set `min-height: 150px` on the footer, and when the list and the languages dropdown are side by side there's enough space left within that 150px for the `.`.  When it's smaller and they stack, the footer is taller than 150px so that `.` is actually coming after.  You can test this by removing the `min-height` and then you'll have the error on all screen sizes.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7WD7/1/)**

Even better is the micro clearfix:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```